# Exclusion inclusion principle

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of ways in which alphabets a,b,c and d can be arranged such that b does not follow a , and c does not follow b , and d does not follow c ?

My attempt - Find the total number of ways = 24 
then find the number of ways in which at least one pair is there in the arrangement = $3*3!$   ( basically  number of ways in which each pair can be chosen and then the possible arrangements for each pair )

Now since we are counting some of the permutations twice , infact all those permutations which contain two pairs will be counted twice so we add those pairs back again. Which is ${3  \choose2 } * 2$ . Now we observe that the permutation a,b,c,d has been counted thrice so we add one. ( Since it has been removed once by choosing two pairs but needs to be removed once again )

Hence we add one to the final answer .

24 - 18 +6 + 1 = 13

But the correct answer is 11 .

Please suggest a better way , and tell me where am I going wrong ?

Comment: The last term should be $-1$. In essentially all standard Inclusion/Exclusion arguments, the signs alternate.

Comment: Could you explain how and why do the signs alternate ?

It will be great if you could give me a reference link to learn the exclusion and inclusion argument in general.

Comment: See [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we subtract $\binom{3}{1}3!$ from $4!$, we subtract the identity permutation $3$ times from the total number of permutations. When we add back $\binom{3}{2}2!$, we are adding back $3$ times the identity permutation. So the expression $4!-\binom{3}{1}3!+\binom{3}{2}2!$ has subtracted the identity permutation $3$ times, and added it back $3$ times, for a net change of $0$. So in the expression, the identity permutation is counted once.

However, the identity permutation *is not* one of our good permutations. So we must subtract $1$ from $4!-\binom{3}{1}3!+\binom{3}{2}2!$ to get a count of the good permutations.